# Trying to return two variable from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hi I am trying to return two variables from a function using the following code:

```
$img_width = 4000;
$img_height = 3000;
function change_large_image_size($img_width, $img_height)
{
    if(($width == $height) && ($width > 790) && ($height > 790)){$case = 1;}
    if($width < $height && ($width > 790) && ($height > 790)){$case = 2;}
    if($width > $height && ($width > 790) && ($height > 790)){$case = 3;}

    switch($case)
    {
        case 1:
            $new_width = 790;
            $new_height = 790;

        break;

        case 2:
            $new_height = 790;
            $ratio = $new_height / $height;
            $new_width = round($width * $ratio);
        break;

        case 3:
            $new_width = 790;
            $ratio = $new_width / $width;
            $new_height = round($height * $ratio);

        break;

        default:
            $new_width = $img_width;
            $new_height = $img_height;
        break;

    }

    return array($new_width, $new_height);
}
list($new_width, $new_height) = change_large_image_size($img_width, $img_height);

        echo '<p>' . $img_width . $img_height . '<br>' . $new_width . $new_height . '</p>';
```

solved the initial problem I was having but have a new one
For some reason the function keeps throwing out the default case in the switch.

Comment: Use echo($new_width) throughout the function to determine how far you're getting, what the variable(s) are getting set to...etc etc.  If you STILL can't figure it out, at least let us know what the variable is before the "return" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously none of your three conditions hold, so `$case` ends up evaluated as `null` in the `switch` statement and the default branch is taken.

Comment: Thanks it was a simple variable naming issue, dooh

Answer (score 0):

make two functions. One for width one for height

Comment: Forgot to rename some of the variables within the function after changing their names in the calling program, doh! It works now